# If gram isn't part of the SI system, then how is it that SI recognizes its symbol?

Tags: units, si-units

If gram is of the CGS system of measurement (which is a variant of the metric system, which is still used), then how does SI recognize its symbol? When it is not part of SI. What does this statement from this source mean?
[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram

Comment: gram is a part of the SI system for measurement of mass. A unit can be used in CGS and SI. The most commonly cited rift between SI and CGS is in EM since there's some notable pros/cons in what constants get added to maxwell's EQs

Comment: The centimeter is also a valid SI unit.

Comment: @SeñorO Source please?

Comment: @G.Smith Can you share your source as well, please?

Comment: See Chapter 3 of the SI [defining document](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf/2d2b50bf-f2b4-9661-f402-5f9d66e4b507?version=1.9&download=true) from the BIPM.

Comment: @ShahzadRahim any system using the metric system would recognize the gram as a unit of measure since it is the base unit of mass. The SI system uses the metric system therefore the gram is an SI unit.

Comment: @Triatticus The gram is *not* SI’s base unit of mass. See section 2.3.1.

Comment: @G.Smith I didn't say it was, I said it was the base unit of the metric system.

Comment: @Triatticus Chapter 3 only states that when stating multiples or submultiples we can use the standard SI prefixes, in which we use them "as if" gram were the base. So we don't write microkilogram and ya the same applies to the meter. but It doesn't say anything about "gram" being recognized in SI. However, I do think that since they are both metric systems it does recognize gram  but it's not just part of it.

Answer (score 1):

As it is known, in 1960 BIPM officially adopted MKS over CGS for the so-called system of base units, but that didn't mean the gram was deemed obsolete, nor eliminated from SI, it was just no longer a base unit. The correct phrasing would be: "In SI, mass is officially reported in base units of kilograms (in the official MKS system), but also in grams (as part of the alternative CGS system)."

Comment: Can you please share your source? Where this is stated or even implied? I appreciate the response.

Comment: The gram wasn't part of SI to begin with so how can it be eliminated? It's been part of CGS system. SI is the modern system of the metric system which defines "kg" as it's base unit. So you can't report mass in grams if you are using SI, you can only do that through "kg", if you did use gram then you would be using CGS.